# Привязать выполнние js к сессии пользователя

Tags: javascript

На сайте исполняется код на разных страницах при нажатии пользователем кнопки, как сделать, чтобы за одну сессию пользователя код не исполнялся более одного раза (нажатие #submit на разных страницах сайта)?

```
jQuery('#submit').on('click', function() {
  fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
    value: '200.00',
    currency: 'RUB'
  });
});
```

Я думаю, что можно создать куку, но как добавить условие в код не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function doOnce() {
  if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)only_one_operation\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
    alert("Hello world!"); // Операция, которая должна быть выполнена единожды
    document.cookie = "only_one_operation=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
  }
}
```

Comment: Это работает, спасибо. Но, я хотел удалять куки в конце сессии. Для этого убрал из Вашего кода "expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" проверил в двух браузерах, но это не сработало почему-то. После перезапуска браузера кука осталась и в ФФ и в хроме.

Comment: Вы правильно сделали - если дата окончания не указана - куки будут удалятся при закрытии браузера. Но Вам скорее всего нужно вручную удалить предыдущий "вечный" куки в браузере.

Comment: Немного вник в вопрос, просроченная кука удаляется браузером при закрытии, в моем случае были другие куки, которые давали понять браузеру, что сессия не окончена, даже если закрывался браузер и only_one_operation=true оставалась после перезапуска. Помогло указание время жизни в пол часа.